# cleaning columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can someone help me clean the 'player' and 'signed' columns, my mentor wants me to use a for loop to iterate through the string characters to get rid of the last name in the front of each player. Instead of using regex, thanks!

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnc6e.png)

data

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Player':['ColeGerrit Cole', 'RendonAnthony Rendon', 'StrasburgStephen Strasburg'],
                   'signed':['157609919612/11/19', '157609143612/11/19', '157591351012/09/19']})

df['Player'] = df['Player'].str.extract('[A-Z][a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]+)(\s\w+)').sum(1)

df['signed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['signed'].str[-8:])

df
```

Output:

```
              Player     signed
0        Gerrit Cole 2019-12-11
1     Anthony Rendon 2019-12-11
2  Stephen Strasburg 2019-12-09
```

Answer (score 0):

see that your mentor wants you to use loops... try this one here

```js
df = pd.DataFrame({'Player':['ColeGerrit Cole', 'RendonAnthony Rendon', 'StrasburgStephen Strasburg'],
               'signed':['157609919612/11/19', '157609143612/11/19', '157591351012/09/19']})


a = df.Player
for i,j in enumerate(a):
for x,y in enumerate(j):
    if y == y.upper() and x>1:
        a[i] = a[i][0:x]
df.Player =a
df.head()
```

this will remove anything that's Upcassed onward after the first name